# NSCalendar gives wrong week numbers by month in year

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar, week-number

I have a function which returns an array of week numbers due to month and year.

Here is the code:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let weekRange = calendar.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, inUnit: .CalendarUnitMonth, forDate: NSDate())
weekArray = Array(weekRange.location..<weekRange.location + weekRange.length)
```

**Example:** for 2015-08-21 it will return [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36] which is correct due to [this website](http://week-number.net/calendar-with-week-numbers-2015.html).

It works fine when but I found one mistake if I pass this date "2016-01-01" it returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] but the correct array should be [53 (from 2015 year), 1, 2, 3, 4] (again checked on [this website](http://week-number.net/calendar-with-week-numbers-2016.html)).

As mentioned on that website:

> The first week of the year (WN 1) is the week containing january 4th or the first tuesday of the Year.

So, I have to write some calculation to make it works? Or there is an easier solution? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result depends on calendar type, locale and first weekday of week settings.

The calendar on the mentioned website is based on ISO 8601, your `currentCalendar()` probably on Gregorian, both types are similar but not identical.

Please check this out in a playground and try also to uncomment the commented line and provide other locale identifiers.

The code is for Swift 2.0, in Swift 1.2 use `.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear` and `.CalendarUnitMonth`

```
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.year = 2016
components.month = 1

var weekNumbersForCalendarIdentifier = { ( identifier : String) -> [Int] in
  let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: identifier)!
  // calendar.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "us_POSIX")
  let weekRange = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.WeekOfYear, inUnit: .Month, forDate: calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!)
  return Array(weekRange.location..<weekRange.location + weekRange.length)
}

let resultISO = weekNumbersForCalendarIdentifier(NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
let resultGregorian = weekNumbersForCalendarIdentifier(NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
```

There is one particular behavior independent of the different settings:

> `NSCalendar` displays the ordinal number `0` rather than the actual
>   number 52 or 53 of the preceding year.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you save my day twice!)

Comment: Using "NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian" calendar identifier and setting calendar "locale" did the trick.                                                                                                              let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: identifier)!
     calendar.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()